# How to hide specific icon in menu bar? Mojave OS

Tags: menu-bar

I have a requirement to hide specific icon in menu bar (McAfee icon). Tried using "LSUIPresentationMode" in info.plist but still the icon is visible. Any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different. Which McAfee software does the icon belong to? Isn't there a setting in Preferences to toggle displaying the icon (many apps offer such a setting)? Could you provide the full path to the Info.plist file you modified?

Answer (score 1):

> To remove an icon from the status bar:
>
> - Hold down <kbd>cmd</kbd>
> - Click the icon you want to remove and drag it to the desktop (A cross icon should appear)
> - Let go of the left mouse button

[Source](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/rearrange-macos-menu-bar-icons/)